# Regex to get NUMBER only from String

Tags: c#, regex

I recieve "7+" or "5+" or "+5" from XML and wants to extract only the number from string using Regex.
e.g Regex.Match() function

```
        stringThatHaveCharacters = stringThatHaveCharacters.Trim();
        Match m = Regex.Match(stringThatHaveCharacters, "WHAT I USE HERE");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
        return number;
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`\d+`

`\d` represents any digit, `+` for one or more. If you want to catch negative numbers as well you can use `-?\d+`.

Note that as a string, it should be represented in C# as `"\\d+"`, or `@"\d+"`

Answer (score 157):

The answers above are great.  If you are in need of parsing all numbers out of a string that are nonconsecutive then the following may be of some help:

```
string input = "1-205-330-2342";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");
Console.WriteLine(result); // >> 12053302342
```

Comment: Regex.Replace(input, @"\D", "");

Answer (score 6):

Either `[0-9]` or `\d`<sup>1</sup> should suffice if you only need a single digit. Append `+` if you need more.

---

1 The semantics are slightly different as `\d` potentially matches *any* decimal digit in any script out there that uses decimal digits.

Comment: please define exact regex to use in Regex.Match function.... Because i m not good in Regex (SYNTAX)

Comment: For a single digit you don't need a regex: `char digit = s.First(Char.IsDigit);`. I'd add that to my answer, but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: @Kobi: That would still need explicit iteration over the string, though. Most people opting to use regex wouldn't want to do this :-)

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan, var newInput = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");