# C# - Search for digits in string with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, int

I want to extract digits from a string, formatted as following:

```
string foo="something%4%something2%5%";
```

How do I write this with Regex?

```
//pseudocode
foo.GetDigits("%"+{int}+"%").ToArray();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related [Regex to get NUMBER only from String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4792242/1577396)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(foo, @"%(\d+?)%").Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: This will fail to capture the `2`, as it doesn't have a `%` before it. Having said that, it is not clear from the question whether the `2` should or should not be extracted...

Comment: @Oded `GetDigits("%"+{int}+"%")` makes me think that it must be between two `%`s

Comment: I suspect the something2 is just... the second something. An unfortunate naming of the value. =)

Comment: NB I think the lazy-thing (`?`) isn't necessary here as `\d` doesn't overlap with `%`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of Regex, you can use [char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isdigit.aspx) method to get all the digits from the string.

```
string str = "something%4%something2%5%";
string digitstr = new string(str.Where(r => char.IsDigit(r)).ToArray());
```

Or shorter:

```
string digitstr = new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Would be great if the down voter can explain what is wrong with the answer ?

Comment: Pain in the ass dvs with no constructive criticism. Happened to me the other day... good answer though, +1.

Comment: Probably because you're not providing a regex. I prefer this solution though because of the sheer clarity of what's going on. Not *absolutely everything* should or can be done with regex.

Comment: This loses any information about which digits are contiguous, although from the question it's not clear if OP cares.

Comment: @Rawling, by contiguous do you mean  `str= "2222aaa222";` ?

Comment: Yup; this'll just give a lot of twos with no indication of the fact they were grouped in a 4 and a 3, right? I'd _expect_ the OP cares about this, but it's not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern too:

```
(\d+)(?=%)
```

Here is a sample code: (untested)

```
MatchCollection mcol = System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.Matches(foo,"(\d+)(?=%)");

foreach (Match m in mcol)
{
   System.Diagnostic.Debug.Print(m.ToString());
}
```

This pattern will capture all digit(s) followed by `%`.

hope it helps!