# Get Number from the string using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to capture number from my error message i.e something like this

> Command parameter[8] '' data value could not be converted for reasons

Does anyone know how to get the number i.e. 8 from the following string using regular expression in c#?

Comment: `\d` Also: do you literally mean a "digit" or a "number"?

Comment: You've obviously searched for existing answers and found stuff like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792242/regex-to-get-number-only-from-string. Would you mind to clarify what problem you have applying solutions suggested in existing answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
\[([0-9]+)\]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mE0rX2/2

**Edit**: If you want to restrict matches to strings in the form of "`parameter[digits_here]`", use the following pattern:

```
^parameter\[([0-9]+)\]$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xE3tY4/1

**Edit1:** Code snippet in VB.net. Hopefully, you can translate that to C#

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim str As String : str = "parameter[8]"
            Dim regex As New Regex("^parameter\[([0-9]+)\]$")
            For Each m In regex.Matches(str)
                MsgBox(m.groups(1).ToString)
            Next
        End Sub

    End Module
```

output:
[image]

Comment: is there a way to say find the number which is only in the string 'parameter[8]' ?

Comment: var regexResult = Regex.Match("parameter[8]", @"^parameter\[([0-9]+)\]$");   this returns 'paramter[8]' as result. I thought it would return number 8 only.

Comment: looks like it doesn't work if it has other words i.e. 'Command parameter[8] data..'. Is there a way if i can get the number from sentence which has word parameter. More like check in this sentence, if it has parameter word and get the number inside the bracket of word parameter?

Comment: change the pattern to "parameter\[([0-9]+)\]"

Answer (score 0):

If the number is going to be the only number in the string then simply the pattern by just searching for a number:

`\d+` - Which says match on a number `+` one or more.