# How can i get rid of from nonnumeric values

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

i want to erase all non numeric values including space,punctiation marks etc. in a string. This is bank account and i want to write it in another order only with its numbers. i tried to write some codes in c# but couldn't success. Can anyone write some basic codes for me?

```
    private void btn_convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList account= new ArrayList();

        for(int i=0 ; i<textBox1.Lines.Length ; i++)
        {
            char[] str = textBox1.Lines[i].ToCharArray();

            for(int j=0; j<str.Length; j++ )
            {
                if ((str[j] >= 0 && str[j] <= 9) == true)
                {
                    account.Add(str[j]);
                }
                else continue;
            }

        }

        string[] newaccount= (string[])account.ToArray(typeof(string));
        label1.Text = newaccount[1];                     

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll find someone willing to do your work for you soon enough. In the meantime, some notes you should keep in mind: `char` values are not the same as numeric literals like `0` and `9` and can't be compared to them directly (try comparing with `'0'` and `'9'` instead); it is not necessary to convert a string to `char[]` to index the characters, the string itself can be indexed; you need to clarify whether you want simply to remove non-digit characters from strings, or to ignore any line of text that itself contains any non-digit characters. It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792242/regex-to-get-number-only-from-string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably by using `Regex`, something simple like this will suffice:

```
string input = "foo-bar-123:+-456";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");
```

This will print `123456`.

Your case could probably get simplified to only this:

```
private void btn_convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"[^\d]", "");    
}
```