# Sorting Numbers in a List/Textbox with additional Text

Tags: c#

I have Numbers with (additional Text), and i need to Sort the Numbers (small to big)..
My Code looks like;

```
decimal xy = Convert.ToDecimal(number);
decimal xy1 = Convert.ToDecimal(number1);
List<decimal> manynumbers = new List<decimal>();
manynumbers.Add(xy);
manynumbers.Add(xy1);
manynumbers.Sort();
```

and then i write the sorted numbers with a foreach in my textbox

```
foreach (decimal z in manynumbers)
{
AppendTextBox2(Convert.ToString(z));
}
```

and the textBox looks like;

1

2

AppendTextBox looks like;

```
    public void AppendTextBox2(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox2), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        textBox15.Text += value + " \r\n";
    }
```

This works very well, but when i "add" Text behind the Number i have no output in the textBox(without a error..)

i was trying so but didnt work...

```
decimal xy = Convert.ToDecimal(number + "TestXY");
```

Comment: You can't convert a  a string that contains charterers to decimal or any other type that represent numbers, what are you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: so if you have 1TestXY, 11TestXY and 2TestXy, what order do you expect them to be in?

Comment: Wait did he say `without a error` ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Im trying to sort my textbox(multiline) with numbers (from big to small) with text, lets say: 453 JASD and 9393 XY, sorted -> 9393 XY and 453 JASD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would suggest that displaying a list is better done with a `ListBox` than a `TextBox`.

From your answer, it looks to me that your data is separated and you're combining it into 1 string to display it.  If this is the case, I would suggest a simple class(`Item`) with 2 fields, will make representing the data much easier.

Combining these 2 suggestions all that's missing is overriding the `ToString()` method to allow a `List<Item>` to be sorted by the decimal field and displayed in the `ListBox`, by assigning the List as the DataSource.  A form with a ListBox would display the data something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private class Item
    {
        public decimal fieldA = 0;
        public string fieldB = "";
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{fieldA}{fieldB}";
        }
    }
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item{fieldA = 3.8M,fieldB = "klsd"},
        new Item{fieldA = 84.6M,fieldB = "jio"},
        new Item{fieldA = 64.97M,fieldB = "gjidf"}
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = items.OrderBy(x => x.fieldA).ToList();
    }
}
```

To reverse the order use `items.OrderByDescending(x => x.fieldA).ToList()`

Comment: wow, thank you for your input, this is too very helpfull, thank you :)

Comment: @Kabundscha - You're welcome.  I just noticed that you require Descending order not Ascending.  I added the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an invalid string to decimal.

You could use a List of string instead and sort it without convert to decimal but that will result in alphanumeric sort. Or remove the aditional text with some regular expression. see [Regex to get NUMBER only from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792242/regex-to-get-number-only-from-string)

Edited:

You also could create your own string comparer

```
 public class MyStringComparer : Comparer<string>, IComparer<string>
    {
        public override int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            decimal dx = Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Replace(x, @"[^\d]", ""));
            decimal dy = Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Replace(y, @"[^\d]", ""));
            return Convert.ToInt32(dx - dy);
        }
    }
```

and then use in the sort

```
List<string> manynumbers = new List<string>();
        manynumbers.Add("1.11 text");
        manynumbers.Add("1.1 text");
        manynumbers.Sort(new MyStringComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sorting strings that has numbers, you can use a `list<string>` and call `sort()` on it.

```
string xy = 4 + "TestXY";
string xy1 = 2 + "TestXY";

List<string> manynumbers = new List<string>();

manynumbers.Add(xy);
manynumbers.Add(xy1);
manynumbers.Sort();


foreach (string z in manynumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(z);
}
```

That will out put

```
2TestXY
4TestXY
```

EDIT : In your case this should be convenient.

```
// Getting the input from multiline Textbox, splitting the content by a linebreak.
string[] input = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Since it's an array we can pass it as an argument to a list.
List<string> manynumbers = new List<string>(input);

// Then call sort()
manynumbers.Sort();
```