# Julia - Extract number from string using regex

Tags: regex, julia

I have a list of strings each telling me after how many iterations an algorithm converged.

```
string_list = [
    "Converged after 1 iteration", 
    "Converged after 20 iterations", 
    "Converged after 7 iterations"
]
```

How can I extract the number of iterations? The result woudl be `[1, 20, 7]`. I tried with regex. Apparently `(?<=after )(.*)(?= iteration*)` will give me anything in between `after` and `iteration` but then this doesn't work:

```
occursin(string_list[1], r"(?<=after )(.*)(?= iteration*)")
```

Comment: How about just `/\d+/g`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to get NUMBER only from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792242/regex-to-get-number-only-from-string)

Comment: Maybe `r"\d+(?=\s+iteration)"` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great little Julia package that makes creating regexes easier called [ReadableRegex](https://github.com/jkrumbiegel/ReadableRegex.jl), and as luck would have it the first example in the readme is an example of finding every integer in a string:

```
julia> using ReadableRegex

julia> reg = @compile look_for(
                       maybe(char_in("+-")) * one_or_more(DIGIT),
                       not_after = ".",
                       not_before = NON_SEPARATOR)
r"(?:(?<!\.)(?:(?:[+\-])?(?:\d)+))(?!\P{Z})"
```

That regex can now be broadcast over your list of strings:

```
julia> collect.(eachmatch.(reg, string_list))
3-element Vector{Vector{RegexMatch}}:
 [RegexMatch("1")]
 [RegexMatch("20")]
 [RegexMatch("7")]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works if there's a string which doesn't contain any matches.

Answer (score 3):

To extract information out of a regex, you want to use `match` and `captures`:

```
julia> convergeregex = r"Converged after (\d+) iteration"
r"Converged after (\d+) iteration"

julia> match(convergeregex, string_list[2]).captures[1]
"20"

julia> parse.(Int, [match(convergeregex, s).captures[1] for s in string_list])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
 20
  7
```

`\d+` matches a series of digits (so, the number of iterations here), and the parantheses around it indicates that you want the part of the string matched by that to be placed in the results `captures` array.

You don't need the lookbehind and lookahead operators (`?<=`, `?=`) here.